# haproxy adding dynamic header in health check httpchk

Tags: haproxy

I have a requirement where I need to do health check and the exposed health check api requires a uniqueId header, How can i set this header to a different unique value in haproxy.cfg file . My configuration is as below:

```
backend server_1
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /health HTTP/1.0\r\nuniqueId:\ <needs random uniqueid here>
    http-check expect status 200
    server app1 127.0.0.1:8083 check
```

Comment: This looks correct. What are you seeing happen when you monitor the traffic?

Comment: When i add some variable in place of <needs random uniqueid here> like %[rand()] , it doesn't get resolved and it is printed as it is , I want it to be resolved with a new value everytime.

Comment: @PunitGoel Did you ever get this working?